# How to develop billing system in jhipster microservice application

Tags: microservices, jhipster

I am currently working on a microservice based application which now includes a gateway, a uaa, two micro services.

The application use password grant to get access and refresh token, once authenticated, all microservices will be awared.

Now I want to add billing information for each user, e.g. after purchase some product (one month or one year), he/she will be allowed to access the two micro services.

I have three options now:

1. store billing information in uaa mysql table (jhi_user), when request coming in to access the two services, use feign client to get information from uaa to microservice.
2. develop another billing microservice, use feign client to get information from the microservice.
3. copy billing information to each of the two microservices (store in their own databases).

I want to know which one is better. Another question is, if choose from 1 & 2, there will be a lot of communication (check billing information for each request) among microservices through restful API, that will impact the performance?

Appreciated for any idea.

Answer (score 0):

Of the three I tend to favor the third option.For both option 1 and 2 the pros include guarantees that information is current and accurate. Option 1 will lower the complexity of the project, and option 2 though increasing complexity it would make it easier to scale the application. But in either the first or the second each call will await a call to the feign client in order to guarantee authorization and that might slow down response times. 
That's why I feel that the third option is better in the long term. The response time is faster since responses do not await feign calls. 
Sure there are no guarantees that authorization information is current, but the same can easily be synchronized by use of a messaging platform at and during creation of billing data. The guarantee can additionally be offered by maintaining a micro service or a batch that continually iterates over your data.
But if guarantee that information is current is required and speed of response if not a requirement, by all means go with option 2. If both guarantee and speed is a requirement, then I would probably go with option 1. Otherwise option three is to be preferred.